# Set Default Record Types to avoid Post Deployment activity for each user

Tags: salesforce1-app, profile, record-type

**Problem:**
Need to restrict popup '***Record Type selection screen***' while new custom object record creation.

I tried added under permission set for profile under Default Record type,as shown in below image
[image] but after deploying to another salesforce Org, user manually needs to visit ***[View Profile > Settings > Display & Layout > Set Default Record Types]*** this remain unchecked, until and unless user manually not make this checkbox true, the screen for record type selection is keep on coming.
[image]

**My Thoughts:**
Can we write some script or something that on one click every post deployment meta field gets updated, because user is not happy with this point and click of and if there are 100 users every users needs to do the same one time activity.

Thanks,
Pranav

Comment: Not sure if that works (never did it) but why not update or insert a Profile via the **Metadata API**. 
The Apex wrapper lib from https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi seems to support the `Profile` object including the `ProfileRecordTypeVisibility` subclass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's no way to set this with a script. Metadata deployments can only access "public" information. Almost anything in My Personal Information are not accessible, including using default record types, email signatures, etc.